# Javascript - Get the coordination of element in frame to root parent frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the X coordination of the button to the root document like in picture.

I try to use offsetLeft of JQuery, but it only return the x of current frame :

```
$(window).on('click',
    function(e){
        console.log("x: " + e.target.offsetLeft);
    }
);
```

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHbpR.jpg

So I want to know that is there a method to get direct the x in situation like that ?

Comment: Maybe use `$(document)` instead of `$(window)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("button").on('click', function()
{
// Your code
});
```

In this case, the x value will be 8 as the default margin of the body is 8px.

```js
$("button").on('click',
  function(e) {
    console.log("x: " + e.target.offsetLeft);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: Your method only return the x of current frame.

Comment: The <frame> tag itself is one seperate document. So when you get offsetLeft, it only can take the x of the current document/frame (in my picture it is the 3rd column).

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript to each file:

```
$(window).on('click',
  function(e) {
    console.log(getLeft()+e.target.offsetLeft);
  }
);

function getLeft() {
  if (window.parent!=window) {
    var result="foo";
    $(window.parent.document).find("iframe").each(function() {
      if ($(this)[0].contentWindow==$(window)[0]) {
        result=this.offsetLeft+window.parent.getLeft();
      }
    });
    if (result!="foo") return result;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A sample of an html containing `test2.html` would be:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>foo</button>
  <iframe src="test2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This works by getting the position of the iframe from the parent.
Feel free to comment on this if you have any questions :)

*P.S. `<frame>` is obsolete/deprecated. The example is using `<iframe>`.*

Comment: But in my case it has 2 parents. How  can i get the root parent ?

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your kindly answer. But it seem that we need to insert the js file contain `getLeft` method to "each" html file right ?

In my case, the project only contain 1 js file to interact with the browser (because we don't control the html file, it can be any web page). 

So when I meet the code `window.parent.getLeft()` again (2nd time), it can't call the `getLeft` method in parent (because there is not that method in parent)

I would like to bother you again.

Comment: Yes, you need to insert the js to every file. You can try insert the script dynamically through javascript on one file to its parents/children if you only have control over one single html though.